# Click a button by it's text in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to click multiple buttons on a page with containt text [collect now] but it's giving element not interactable error. I have also attached the image of html body and web page screen shot

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable

---

[image: html body]

[image: page ss]

[page link](https://www.amazon.in/b?node=21102071031&ref_=apay_deskhome_YourRewards)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
#import logindata
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = "username@gmail.com"
password = "username"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedata\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
action = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(1)


driver.get('http://www.amazon.in')
time.sleep(1)


firstLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-link-accountList"]/span/span')
action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform()
time.sleep(1)
 
secondLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-flyout-ya-signin"]/a/span')
secondLevelMenu.click()
#time.sleep(1)

signinelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ap_email"]')
signinelement.send_keys(username)
#time.sleep(1)

cont = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="continue"]')
cont.click()
#time.sleep(1)

passwordelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ap_password"]')
passwordelement.send_keys(password)
#time.sleep(1)

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="signInSubmit"]')
login.click()
#time.sleep(1)

'----------------------------X-------------------------X------------------------------------------------'

zpay = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-xshop"]/a[1]')
zpay.click()

rwards = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="YourRewards"]/span/a/div[1]/span')
rwards.click()

time.sleep(3)


rwards = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-autoid-7"]')
rwards.click()


`HERE COMES ERROR`

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Collect Now')]")
time.sleep(3)

for btn in buttons:
    btn.click()
```

Comment: is it in Selenium view port ?

Comment: browser - chrome ,  terminal - pycharm @cruisepandey

Comment: What I meant was, when Selenium opens up a browser, can it see these 4 section ? Is it in view port ?

Comment: yes @cruisepandey

Comment: Can you share the exact URL , not this one `http://www.amazon.in` ?

Comment: edited in the post  @cruisepandey